# How do I hide "TeamViewer is still running" notification?

Tags: windows, teamviewer

How do I hide "*TeamViewer is still running*" notification?

I enabled the setting ["*Close to tray menu*"](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/How-to-minimize-to-tray/td-p/5713). Now, every time I close the main window, the following notification pops up. It's so annoying!

- System: Windows 10 x64 (version 1709)
- Teamviewer: 13.0.5640

[image]

Answer (score 11):

1. Go into your registry (regedit.exe)
2. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ TeamViewer
   ```
3. Create a new DWORD called **ShowTaskbarInfoOnMinimize** . Leave it's value on 0
4. Close the registry editor to save your setting

Restart Teamviewer and test it

Comment: As an aside, I haven't had this on TV13, but I've upgraded from earlier versions, at least one of which had a "Hide future notifications" check-box, and this setting has been maintained through the upgrades.

Comment: Not working for Teamviewer 15 on Windows 10. No option to deactivate it or not to show this invidual message anymore. I can only deactivate notifications for the whole application, which is not what I want, because I want to see messages when a remote computer comes online.

Comment: Works for me in 2022 on Windows 11, TeamViewer 15.3 (free). Thanks